# change heightAnchor of higher size then current size is not working

Tags: swift, constraints, swift5, ios-autolayout

I have one view whose height is 50

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

Now what I want to do is when I click button (buton1), I want to change its height to 20. So I make below and it's working fine.

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
```

Now in `myView` I have another button (button2), when I click on it, I want to go back to previous height of 50, but it's not working.

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

Problem is here. Now the view is not re-sizing like when click on button1.

Note :

When I click on button1 & use below code, re-size also not work.

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

***What I found is if I try to re-size to higher size of current size, it don't work.***

Any idea why view is not re-sizing?

---

### Edit 1

Even I wrote below after updating height anchor but still not working.

```
myView.layoutIfNeeded()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

---

### Edit 2

***Working `Option 1`***

When click on `button1`, I do below and works.

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

When click on `button2`, I do below and works.

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

***Not Working `Option 2`***

When click on `button1`, I do below and works.

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

When click on `button2`, I do below and `NOT WORK`.

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

***So what I found is I change height higher then previous, it don't work***

Comment: Have you tried using `view.layoutIfNeeded()`?

Comment: @Rob : Yes, I did. I have updated question.

Comment: heya, what you're doing atm is creating a new rule every time. that will create multiple rules about the height which are in conflict, so iOS can't resolve what you want to do. you need to follow @frankenstein 's answer and keep a reference beside your IBoutlet variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you are creating a new rule about the view's height every time. iOS doesn't understand how to make a view both 10, 20 and 30 pixels high, so it will do the lowest one. To avoid creating conflicting heights, you need to have one height rule and change that one's constant when needed. Here's a somewhat contained example.

```
class CoolView: UIViewController {

    lazy var myView = UIView()
    lazy var myViewHeightAnchor = myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myView.backgroundColor = .black//livesMatters
        myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(myView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10),
            myViewHeightAnchor
        ])
    }

    @objc func someButtonTapped() {
        myViewHeightAnchor.constant = 20
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    @objc func anotherButtonTapped() {
        myViewHeightAnchor.constant = 30
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: let's create another function as anotherButtonTapped where constant is 30. Let's say someButtonTapped & anotherButtonTapped is called on 2 different buttons. If u try to click 2 buttons, only first click works. Rest click height will not update.

Comment: @FahimParkar If `anotherButtonTapped` also modifies the `myViewHeightAnchor` variable, that will work. If you create a new rule, like you are here: `myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true`,  it will not work. I updated the code to add another button.

Comment: Exactly what I said.

Comment: @Frankenstein Maybe this answer just explained it more clearly

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the reference to the constraint and change the constant value and then call layoutIfNeeded method to achieve this. Here's how:

```swift
// First
let heightConstraint = myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
heightConstraint.isActive = true
// Then to change
heightConstraint.constant = 20
myView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

As requested I'm adding playground sample here (try this out on Xcode-playground):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sampleView = UIView()
        sampleView.backgroundColor = .green
        sampleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(sampleView)

        heightConstraint = sampleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)

        let button = UIButton(type: .contactAdd)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            sampleView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            sampleView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            heightConstraint!,
            sampleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
        ])
    }

    @objc func handleAction() {
        heightConstraint?.constant = heightConstraint?.constant == 50 ? 30 : 50
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ViewController())
```

Here you can see how updating the `heightConstraint` changes the height of the `sampleView` when the `button` is clicked. I'm toggling between 50 and 30 points in height here.

Comment: how `let heightConstraint.constant = 20` will work?

Comment: Sorry about that, just loose the `let`. Check now.

Comment: I saw your edits, you seem to be adding new constraints, the previous one that's already created still exists. That is not how you update the constraint.

Comment: I already have 1, then i update and then again i want to update.. so total 3 constraints

Comment: How to achieve what I want then?

Comment: As I've said you're not updating the existing constraint as I've shown here. I could make a small example in the playground if you want.

Comment: Ok, it would be great... i will wait

Answer (score 0):

So short story,

I was adding below line every time I want to update height which is wrong.

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

With this, what it do is take the least height and set that. Ex If I set height 3 times as 100, 20, 80, it will take 20 as the height even I run with 80.

To avoid this, we have to add a variable for the height constraint

```
var heightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint?
```

Now while adding constraints to view, add as below.

```
heightConstraint = mainCVView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
heightConstraint!.isActive = true
```

Now whenever you want to update height do it as below instead of adding constraint again.

```
heightConstraint?.constant = 0
heightConstraint?.isActive = true
myView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

***This is most important step and not to add constraint the way I was adding in question***

So whenever you want to update just update constant as show above. That's it.